# MySQL data directory deleted

Tags: mysql, innodb

After a dump import the disks got full and as to try to fix it I just removed the corresponding directory within /var/lib/mysql and now the database doesn't load anymore.

I have some other databases that were running on this server and now none of them works now. All what I want is to load the mysql again to recover the other databases.

I tried to start the database with innodb_force_recovery = 6 and I it didn't work.

May anyone give a clue to solve this problem?

Comment: The information about each table is found both in the `ibdata1` file and in the directory that you deleted.  That is, your attempt to free space is doomed to failure.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share how I have fixed this issue.

I just created a fresh mysql dir with mysql_install_db and then copied all other database directory into it and it worked.